# Como usar modal de alerta dentro de formulário PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, modal

Estou tentando submeter um formulário dentro da mesma página com `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` e a partir disso receber um alerta de "produto cadastrado" com um modal Boostrap. 
Eu acredito que não estou conseguindo linkar a ação `submit` com o alerta.

Código funcionando de *insert* no banco com `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`:

```html
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="boostrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
  <link href="boostrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        INCLUDE "conexao.php";

        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

            $cod_produto = $_POST['cod_produto'];
            $dsc_produto = $_POST['dsc_produto'];
            $preco_produto = $_POST['preco_produto'];
            $qtd_estoque = $_POST['qtd_estoque'];
            $qtd_limitador = $_POST['qtd_limitador'];


            $sql = "INSERT INTO estoque (cod_produto, dsc_produto, preco_produto, qtd_estoque, qtd_limitador) VALUES ('".$cod_produto."', '".$dsc_produto."', '".$preco_produto."', '".$qtd_estoque."', '".$qtd_limitador."')";
            $mysql = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
            if (!mysql) {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error()); 
            }

            else {
                echo "Feito";
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "submit error";
        }       
    }
?>
```

Código com Javascript:

```html
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="boostrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="boostrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        INCLUDE "conexao.php";

        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

            $cod_produto = $_POST['cod_produto'];
            $dsc_produto = $_POST['dsc_produto'];
            $preco_produto = $_POST['preco_produto'];
            $qtd_estoque = $_POST['qtd_estoque'];
            $qtd_limitador = $_POST['qtd_limitador'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO estoque (cod_produto, dsc_produto, preco_produto, qtd_estoque, qtd_limitador) VALUES ('".$cod_produto."', '".$dsc_produto."', '".$preco_produto."', '".$qtd_estoque."', '".$qtd_limitador."')";
            $mysql = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
            if (!mysql) {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error()); 
            }

            else {      
?>
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myInput').focus()
    })
</script>
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<?php
           }
       }
       else {
            echo "submit error";
       }            
   }
?>
```

Não achei relevante colocar o formulário em php, mas acredito que devo alterar o ID dessa linha:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Comment: Não vi a inclusão do arquivo javascript em seu código fonte, você o colocou em seu HTML?

Comment: Coloquei sim `<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Você precisa colocar também o javascript do bootstrap, [veja na documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) como faze-lo.

Comment: Eu coloquei todas que diz na documentação e ainda assim não obtenho nenhuma ação quando clico no botão.

Comment: @Felipe Tinha alguns trechos do código que não estavam aparecendo, editei sua pergunta e corrigi a formatação do código fonte.